# Simple chat client using JMS

Tags: swing, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jms, chat

I'm using Swing, Java Messaging Service and GlassFish4.1 server to build a chat box from a Jpanel so I can add it to my Jframe application; but I seem to have a problem establishing a connection.

During runtime the program stops at the line:

```
TopicConnectionFactory tcf = (TopicConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("BJconn");
```

I previously got this client-code to work on an Enterprise application, but now I'm attempting to add it to a regular Java project I'm rather stuck.

Really appreciate any help on this, I'm very new to JMS so please keep answers as Lamen as possible. Thanks!

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.jms.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;

public class ChatPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel implements Runnable{

private Thread t = null;
private TopicConnection tpConnection = null;
private TopicPublisher tpPublisher = null;
private TopicSession tpSession = null;
private TopicSubscriber tpSubscriber = null;
private final String name;


/**
 * Creates new form chatFrame
 * @param nickName
 */
public ChatPanel(String nickName) 
{
  initComponents();
  DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) gameInfoTextArea.getCaret();
  caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
  name = nickName;
  connect();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialise the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
// </editor-fold>                        

public JTextArea getTextArea()
{
  return gameInfoTextArea;
}        

public void setText(String textString)
{
  String s = gameInfoTextArea.getText() + "\n" + textString; 
  gameInfoTextArea.setText(s);
}        

private void connect()
{
 try
    {
      Context ctx = new InitialContext();
      TopicConnectionFactory tcf = (TopicConnectionFactory) 
              ctx.lookup("BJconn");
      tpConnection = tcf.createTopicConnection();
      tpConnection.setClientID(name);
      tpSession = tpConnection.createTopicSession(false, 
              TopicSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      Topic topic = (Topic) ctx.lookup("BJDest");
      tpPublisher = tpSession.createPublisher(topic);
      tpSubscriber = tpSession.createDurableSubscriber(topic, name);
      tpConnection.start();
      t = new Thread(this);
      t.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Chat cannot connect");
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}        

/*private void closeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    try 
    {
      tpConnection.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage() );
    }        
} */                                                                                       



private void sendMessage()
{
  try
  {
    TextMessage tx = tpSession.createTextMessage();
    tx.setText(name + ": " + this.chatField.getText());
    tpPublisher.send(tx);
    this.chatField.setText("");
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot send message");
  }    
}        

@Override
public void run()
{
  try
  {
    while (true)
    {
      TextMessage tx = (TextMessage) tpSubscriber.receive();
      if (tx != null)
      {
        String content = "";
        content += this.gameInfoTextArea.getText() + "\n" + tx.getText();
        this.gameInfoTextArea.setText(content);
        Thread.sleep(100);
      }    
    }    
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }        
}        

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialise the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    chatField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    gameInfoTextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 0));

    chatField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            chatFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    chatField.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            chatFieldKeyReleased(evt);
        }
    });

    gameInfoTextArea.setEditable(false);
    gameInfoTextArea.setColumns(20);
    gameInfoTextArea.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(gameInfoTextArea);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(chatField)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 358, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 107, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(chatField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void chatFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                         

private void chatFieldKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
    {
      sendMessage();
    } 
}                                     


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField chatField;
private javax.swing.JTextArea gameInfoTextArea;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: In your description, you say that the code shown was working in JEE, but that you are having problems when trying to run the code as a simple Java program. I believe your problem stems from the fact that the `InitialContext` you are creating is not valid, because that context is only valid when running within an enterprise container. This would explain why it works when running as a JEE deployment, but not when running directly as a Java program. But can you add some more detail about what you mean when you say that it is now a Java project? It will help me, or others, to help you.

Comment: I have a project written on netbeans that is a regular java application for a game. This application creates multiple game GUIs in the form of specialised JFrames. Im trying to add a chat box to these frames. Can this be done in a standard edition application? Or would I need to create the chat panel as a seperate JEE project and add it to my current project?

Comment: Yes, you can definitely access JMS from a standalone Java app. Normally, in that case, rather than creating an `InitialContext`, you would retrieve the `TopicConnectionFactory` through some type of `JNDI` lookup. The messaging server will still be deployed as an enterprise service, running within a JEE container, and you simply need to connect your standalone Java client to that server.

Comment: Unless you're giving everyone access to your JMS server (bad idea), you're approach will not work.  You need to have your desktop app send "messages" to your EE app (say, via a REST endpoint).  Your REST bean will act as your producer to fire the TOPIC message.  Your server side MDB will consume the message for each users session and broadcast it your users.  How that is done is a design choice.  You can use web sockets, or your desktop app can poll a REST endpoint.

Comment: Thankyou so much. I ended up recreating my whole project as a JEE Client and added it to a JEE appliction. It works but is this bad practice?

Comment: What do you mean by JEE Client?

Comment: Sorry I'm just going by the terminology from the Netbeans IDE which when creating a project with JEE lists 'Enterprise Application' and 'Enterprise Application Client' as 2 options. Clients can be added as modules of an Enterprise Application.